# Derived model assignment in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider Django model `B` derived from model `A`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # ...

class B(A):
    # ...
```

Now let model `C` refer to `A`:

```
class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey('A')
```

Let's we have an object `c` of class `C`.

Will `c.a = b` (where `b` is an object of class `B`) do the right thing, assigning the primary key of `A` not of `B`?

Comment: When you tested this, what did you find?

Comment: @dfundako The question is not only for myself but for other SO readers, too. So the question would deserve to be answered even if I tested it myself

Comment: You are allowed to self-answer your own posts.

Comment: Methinkest this is a test question which has not actually been tested ...

Comment: @Douglas Agreed. All the code is there, and a succinct question about what will happen. This should be super easy to reproduce and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` and its derived model `B` have the same primary key, because it is implemented as `OneToOneField`.

So the question whether it is the primary key of `A` or of `B` does not make sense, it is the same primary key value for `A` and for `B`.

In short: The assignment `c.a = b` works as expected, because there is only one primary key for `b` to consider.